# How to SUM in XLST Using Value of 1 Element and Attribute of Another

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to iterate through one part of an XML file which lists resources with their Id numbers.  As I do this, I store the ResourceId in a variable $ResId.  Then for each ResourceId I need to iterate through a different portion of the file and sum up the number of hours for which each resource has been assigned to a particular strategy in each of several fiscal years using the StartYear and StartMonth attributes of the WorkUnitsYear element.
  I am able to sum the hours when I leave out the reference to the WorkUnitsYear element, but I have not been able to find the correct syntax for summing with the additional year and month attributes.  So first of all I would like help to figure out how to include the month and year.

Secondly I will need to include somewhat complex logic to the effect that of:
     if (StartYear = '2012' AND StartMonth > 6) OR (StartYear='2013' AND StartMonth < 7) sum to FY13
     and so on for several fiscal years.
  I'm not sure how to implement this logic in XSLT.

Here is a portion of the code I have so far.  Note that I have repeated the line that sums -once with only the Resource ID and once with one of my attempt to include the year.

```
<StrategyPool>
  <Strategy Id="109">
    <StrategyName>TNC CEs SECO</StrategyName>
    <StrategyCalculatedCosts>
      <CalculatedWho>
        <ResourceId>39</ResourceId>
        <ResourceId>43</ResourceId>
      </CalculatedWho>

      <CalculatedCosts>
        <CalculatedWorkUnitsEntries>
          <WorkUnitsEntry>
            <WorkUnitsEntryResourceId>
              <ResourceId>39</ResourceId>
            </WorkUnitsEntryResourceId>
            <WorkUnitsEntryDetails>
              <DateUnitWorkUnits>
                <WorkUnitsDateUnit>
                  <WorkUnitsYear StartYear="2012" StartMonth="7">
                  </WorkUnitsYear>
                </WorkUnitsDateUnit>
                <NumberOfUnits>4</NumberOfUnits>
              </DateUnitWorkUnits>
            </WorkUnitsEntryDetails>
          </WorkUnitsEntry>
          <WorkUnitsEntry>
            <WorkUnitsEntryResourceId>
              <ResourceId>43</ResourceId>
            </WorkUnitsEntryResourceId>
            <WorkUnitsEntryDetails>
              <DateUnitWorkUnits>
                <WorkUnitsDateUnit>
                  <WorkUnitsYear StartYear="2012" StartMonth="7">
                  </WorkUnitsYear>
                </WorkUnitsDateUnit>
                <NumberOfUnits>1</NumberOfUnits>
              </DateUnitWorkUnits>
            </WorkUnitsEntryDetails>
          </WorkUnitsEntry>
        </CalculatedWorkUnitsEntries>
      </CalculatedCosts>
    </StrategyCalculatedCosts>
  </Strategy>
</StrategyPool>
```

The expected output is a table row with the sum of the NumberOfUnits for each ResourceId.
My style sheet then contains the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//StrategyPool/Strategy">
  <xsl:variable name="StrategyId" select="@Id" />
    <xsl:if test="StrategyCalculatedCosts/CalculatedCosts/CalculatedWho/ResourceId[text()=$ResId]">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="StrategyName"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        ID = <xsl:value-of select="$StrategyId"/>    <br />
        <xsl:value-of select="StrategyDetails"/>
        <br />

        <xsl:variable name="CalcNode" select="StrategyCalculatedCosts/CalculatedCosts/CalculatedWorkUnitsEntries" />

        <xsl:value-of select="sum($CalcNode/WorkUnitsEntry[WorkUnitsEntryResourceId/ResourceId=$ResId]/WorkUnitsEntryDetails/DateUnitWorkUnits/NumberOfUnits)" />
        <br />
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($CalcNode/WorkUnitsEntry[WorkUnitsEntryResourceId/ResourceId=$ResId]/WorkUnitsEntryDetails/DateUnitWorkUnits[WorkUnitsYear[@StartYear='2012']]/NumberOfUnits)" />

      </td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The first line containing   [value-of select="sum($CalcNode]  gives the expected total.  The next line, which is similar, attempts to include the StartYear  gives an unexpected total of 0.  I'm looking for help in correcting the syntax of that line.

Comment: There is no CalculatedWho node in your sample input. But you use it in your style-sheet. Is this an error? or is your input document incomplete?

Comment: Please give a better quality sample input document. You may have to simplify your question and sample input down to the nub of your problem. AND THIS IS MOST IMPORTANT: Please show your expected output from the sample input.

Comment: The input document WAS simplified -- to the extent that the CalculatedWho was left out.

Comment: So how is the listing of the expected output coming along?